# How to know MongoDB collection size?

Tags: mongodb

> db.collection.stats()

Response :

```
    "count" : 20696445,
    "size" : NumberLong("1478263842661"),
    "storageSize" : 334732324864,
    "totalIndexSize" : 676327424,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 377094144,
            "leadID_1" : 128049152,
            "leadID_hashed" : 171184128
    },
    "avgObjSize" : 71425.97884134208
```

My actual disk size is matched with **storageSize**. So what is the size and other keys.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/collStats/#collstats-output

Comment: @felix there is a big difference between **size** and **storageSize** .I need more clarification apart from the mongodb document

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the version of MongoDB server you are using but given the `size` of your data is much larger than the `storageSize` on disk, I'm assuming you are using the [WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) which [compresses data and indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30) by default. The WiredTiger storage engine was first available as an option in the MongoDB 3.0 production series and became the default storage engine for new deployments in MongoDB 3.2+.

In your example output it looks like you have 1.4TB of uncompressed `data`  which is currently occupying  334GB on disk (the `storageSize` value). Storage space used by indexes for this collection is reported separately under `indexSizes` and summed up as `totalIndexSize`.

The output of `collection.stats()` will vary depending on your MongoDB server version and configured storage engine, but is generally described in the MongoDB manual as part of the [output of the `collStats` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#output) which is called by the `db.collection.stats()` shell helper.

Note: [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/) is versioned so you should always make sure you are referencing documentation that matches your release series of MongoDB (i.e. 3.2, 3.4, ...). Default documentation links will point to the current production release.

Answer (score 5):

Refer [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#output)

`collStats.size`
The total size in memory of all records in a collection. This value does not include the record header, which is 16 bytes per record, but does include the record’s padding. Additionally size does not include the size of any indexes associated with the collection, which the totalIndexSize field reports.

The scale argument affects this value.

`collStats.storageSize`
The total amount of storage allocated to this collection for document storage. The scale argument affects this value.

`storageSize` does not include index size. See `totalIndexSize` for index sizing.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for my concern **size** is **1.4TB** and **storageSize**  is **334GB** .Why this much space difference exist. How it is calculated ?

Comment: @SelvaKumar WiredTiger compresses your data on disk; 1.4 TB is raw document size, taking 334 GB on disk.